# Two installs of mysql on ubuntu w/ identical char encoding.. but one can't handle Cyrillic

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, character-encoding, internationalization

I have two separate servers which are both running mysql, but only one of them can seem to properly save Cyrillic characters. Since both mysqls are set to latin1 encoding, I'd actually expect neither of them to be capable of handling Cyrillic characters (which I think are 16-bit), but I can't complain.

On the mysql from which cyrillic can be grabbed, the characters display from queries as question marks, but on the mysql which can't, they display as spaces.

What settings for ubuntu or mysql can I look to that would possibly be causing this discrepancy?

Comment: This is way too vague and needs more info. What tool are you using to view the data? How can you tell one can seem to properly save cyrillic characters if all you can see is question marks and spaces? What mySQL versions are running on each? Are you 100% sure the databases and tables are all latin1 encoded? Remember, even columns can have a custom encoding in mySQL.

Comment: Actually, Cyrillic characters does not take 16 bits, it depends on the charset (or encoding).

Comment: Setup A is functioning properly and B isn't. Ultimately I'm using a webapp to view the data; A will display Cyrillic and B will display spaces. In ubuntu mysql, A's Cyrillic data is all question marks and B has nothing but spaces. In both cases defaultCharset is latin1, column charset is utf8 and table engine is InnoDB..

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, this issue seemed to clear up after updating MySQL to 5.5.